# ReadTheDocs says "Could not add webhook"

Tags: read-the-docs

The GitHub integration for https://desert.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ was working fine then the GitHub user account (python-desert) was converted to an organization and since then we (myself and the owner) are unable to get the hook re-synced or deleted/re-added.  I am able to add a webhook on GitHub so it seems my account does have the necessary permissions.  I could delete the project and reconnect it and hope that helps but it would obviously be nice to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks.html#webhook-activation-failed-make-sure-you-have-the-necessary-permissions followed the link to the OAuth apps, already had the RTD app in my user, clicked it, granted permission to the org, deleted the webhook stuff on both GH and RTD, had RTD recreate via the inteagrations...  I still get the following complaint from RTD but the PR did trigger builds on RTD and status callbacks to the PR.

> The project desert doesn't have a valid webhook set up, commits won't trigger new builds for this project. See the project integrations for more information.

Answer (score 1):

@altendky, you got me on the right path, I had to revoke access, then connect again, and it worked.

1. Go to https://github.com/settings/applications
2. Revoke access to ReadTheDocs
3. Go to https://readthedocs.org/ and log-out
4. "Log-in via Github Account" to readthedocs.org
5. Next, the Github OAuth page, be sure to authorize the organization (if applicable)
6. Go to https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/sec-ai/integrations/
7. Click on "Github incoming webhook" if it exists, if not, click "Add integration" and create it
8. Go into the hook and click "Resync webhook"

This fixed it for me.